# Calling a Function Inside a Promise

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

Coming from another main language, I am not completely sure how the resolve() nature of Promises works, thus the basic nature of this question.

My goal is to display a dropdown list (select) elements on screen.  I'm not having difficulty fetching the data and sending it to the template for rendering.  The difficult is that I need to loop through the records and build them into an HTML string in order to support the display we need.  Prior to building them into a string, I need to run a function on the text of each template which will replace some codes with values from the database.

In sequential code, skeleton code might look like:

```
template_recs = get_template_recs(user_id)

for each template_rec

  template_text = template_rec.text

  template_text_new = replace_codes(template_text, user_id)

  template_text_new_html = (html_start + template_text_new + html_end)

  template_options_html = (template_options_html + template_text_new_html)

next

display template_options_html
```

Of course, I would like to develop this in an async way, where the html is wrapped around the template_text after it gets the codes replaced and the display of the entire html occurs after all of the records have been added to the html variable.

I wrote the code below but it's not working.  Before I delve into correcting it, my question is whether this is the best way to go about this.  Am I even on the right track?

I'm working to move a large framework over from synchronous code to nodejs and I want to make sure I get things right from the very beginning.

```
  let get_tt_recs = function() {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

      tt_recs = tt.get(req.user, ind_id, cus_id);

      if (tt_recs) {
        resolve(tt_recs);
      } else {
        reject();
      }

    });

  };

  get_tt_recs.then(function (tt_recs) {

    tt_rec_div = function() {

      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        tt_recs = sms.tt_recs_format(tt_recs);

        if (tt_recs) {
          resolve(tt_recs);
        } else {
          reject();
        }

      });

    };

  }).then(function () {

    complete();

  }).catch(function () {

    console.log('get_tt_recs() did not return any tt_recs');

  });
```

Comment: why are creating Promise twice... why not do the second resolve promise in the first prove..... basically just use one Promise to achieve your task,,,,, since they are linked together....

Comment: Because I don't know how to do that.

Comment: okay.... let me post something for you now

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out.... I think this should work

```
 let get_tt_recs = function() {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

      tt_recs = tt.get(req.user, ind_id, cus_id);
      if(tt_recs !==null) sms_recs = sms.tt_recs_format(tt_recs);

      if (tt_recs && sms_recs ) {
        resolve({tt_recs,sms_recs})

      } else {
        reject();
      }

    });

  };


  get_tt_recs().then(data=> console.log(data)).catch(e =>console.log(e));
```

Comment: you can add your issue in the comment box here.. if it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!  I am getting this error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: get_tt_recs.then is not a function

Comment: It was missing parens and needed to be:

get_tt_recs().then(data=> console.log(data)).catch(e =>console.log(e));

Comment: My bad... I didn't see it... Let me update it.. in case somebody might be able to pick one or two things from it.. and also mark it as answer and vote it up...